# Does apigee-access node module work within express?

Tags: node.js, apigee

I am running this code using express 4 inside apigee Edge:

```
// .....    
router.all('*', function(req, res, next){

console.log(apigee.getVariable(req, 'request.client.ip'));

}
```

I am unable to get any flow variables successfully.

Is apigee-access supported with express middleware req object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express 4 has some bugs in it and it is not supported at this time.  The supported version to use is 3.7.

Comment: any update on this? 10 months later, does it support now?